# Show analytically that 0 is the only zero of $\sin (2x)+2x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

(I know the question sounds a bit confusing but that's how it's written in my book.)

I tried:

$$0 = \sin(2x)+2x \Leftrightarrow \\
0 = 2\sin x \cos x + 2 x \Leftrightarrow \\
0 = 2(\sin x \cos x +x) \Leftrightarrow \\
0 = \sin x \sqrt{1-\sin^2x}+x \Leftrightarrow \\
0 = \sqrt{\sin^2x(1-\sin^2x)}+x \Leftrightarrow \\
0 = \sqrt{\sin^2x-\sin^4x}+x \Leftrightarrow \\
???
$$

What do I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the increasing/decreasing behavior of the function $f(x) = \sin(2x) + 2x$

$f'(x) = 2\cos (2x) + 2$. Since the range of $\cos \theta$ is $[-1, 1]$, we know that $2\cos (2x) + 2 \ge 0$, so $f$ is (non-strictly) increasing for all real numbers.

Comment: That should be a $+$.

Comment: @Nick Ah yes thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Could you show that analitically?

Comment: @MarkRead You mean show that if $f'(x) \ge 0$ for all real numbers, then $f(x)$ is increasing for all real numbers?

Comment: Probably, honestly I am not quite sure. I will play with this exercise a bit.

Comment: @MarkRead Okay. Just remember that when you are trying to prove relationships between functions and their derivatives, the Mean Value Theorem is almost always the way to go, because it's pretty much the only relationship taught between $f$ and $f'$ at no-too-advanced level classes. (Rolle's Theorem is a special case of the MVT)

Comment: Yeah, I think that's it. If the derivative is always positive then this functions is always increasing and so it changes sign only once. Is it possible to find this by solving my equation though? Or if not, why not?

Comment: @MarkRead There could perhaps be a super tricky way to solve that equation algebraically, but I doubt it. For many equatons (especially equations that contain a mix of trig, algebraic, exponential, etc. terms) it has been proven that they are impossible to solve algebraically; the only hope is to either get lucky and spot a solution ($x=0$ in this case) or to approximate the solution numerically (preferably with a computer).

Comment: I see. Thanks..

Comment: @MarkRead You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: There will be no zeros outside of the interval $[-1/2,1/2]$

Comment: Why is that?....

Comment: $|\sin y|\leq 1$ for any input $y$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: if $f(x)=\sin(2x)+2x$ has more than one zero, then $f^{\prime}(x)$ has at least one zero by Rolle's theorem. Show that this is impossible in $[-1,1]$ (for instance).

Comment: I haven't learnt Rolle's theorem yet, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from $0 = \sin(2x)+2x$

Let $f(x)=\sin(2x) +2x$
$f'(x) = 2\cos(2x) + 2 \ge 0$
So it is non-decreasing (with a bunch of inflection points periodically where $f'(x)=0$)

Also notice that $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) > 0$, and thus $0$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

If we replace $2x$ by $x$ we see that we are looking for solutions
to $-\sin x = x$.

It is clear that we only need to consider $|x| \le 1$.

For $x \in [-1,0)$ we have $-\sin x > 0$ and $x <0$ and
for $x \in (0,1]$ we have $-\sin x < 0$ and $x >0$. Hence
the only point left ix $x=0$ which is the solution.